# Matplotlib xlabel plotting error (IndexError: list index out of range)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting several 16 images using matplotlib and labeling their name using the column name from which this images were extracted. I'm running into an issue where the index of the plots and their label is not matching.

here is the worflow I have so far.

```
names = [(i) for i in (columns)]
names
```

the list of the column names is:

```
['value__longest_strike_above_mean',
 'value__longest_strike_below_mean',
 'value__maximum',
 'value__mean',
 'value__mean_abs_change',
 'value__mean_change',
 'value__median',
 'value__minimum',
 'value__number_cwt_peaks__n_12',
 'value__number_cwt_peaks__n_6',
 'value__quantile__q_0.05',
 'value__quantile__q_0.15',
 'value__quantile__q_0.85',
 'value__quantile__q_0.95',
 'value__skewness',
 'value__sum_values']
```

There are 16 names that will be assigned to the plots below.

```
for i in range(0,16):
    img = f2Array[:,:,i]  
    i = i+1
    plt.subplot(4,4,i)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.imshow(img, cmap="gist_earth")
    plt.xlabel((names[i]), fontsize=10)
```

plotting this way gave me the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-284-299c4a617b63> in <module>()
     13     plt.yticks([])
     14     plt.imshow(img, cmap="gist_earth")
---> 15     plt.xlabel((names[i]), fontsize=10)
     16 
     17 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

]

The indexing of the names started from 1 instead of 0 which distorted the labeling. The very last plot also doesn't have a name.

Any idea on how to improve the labeling?

Comment: You started counting from 1 yourself with `i = i+1` inside the loop.

Comment: starting from 0 won't help either @ForceBru, the plt.subplot requires the number to range between 0 and 16 since there are 16 plots.

Comment: If you are sure that there are 16 elements in the list, you shouldn't be getting the IndexError after having removed `i = i+1` from the loop.

Comment: removing the `i= i+1` loop returns error on the `plt.subplot(4,4,i)`.

Comment: Right, because, according to the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html), "`index` _starts at 1_ in the upper left corner and increases to the right.", but your `i` starts from 0, which is thus invalid. If you do `i=i +1`, you change the value of `i`, which leads to the IndexError, because `names[15+1]` doesn't exist. You still need the third argument of `subplot` to be _one more_ than `i`, right? How does one do that?

Comment: All that fuss: why can't you just use `plt.xlabel((names[i-1]), fontsize=10)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refactor your code a bit:

```
for i, name in enumerate(names):
    img = f2Array[:,:,i]  
    plt.subplot(4,4,i + 1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.imshow(img, cmap="gist_earth")
    plt.xlabel((name), fontsize=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

The index of `subplot(nrows, ncols, index, **kwargs)` start at 1. So just remove `i=i+1` and use `plt.subplot(4,4,i+1)`. Try this:

```
for i in range(0,16):
    img = f2Array[:,:,i]  
    plt.subplot(4,4,i+1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.imshow(img, cmap="gist_earth")
    plt.xlabel((names[i]), fontsize=10)
```